# i have problem with displaying nav menu on hover

Tags: html, css

I have problem with displaying nav menu on hover of mouse on another div element.
The button that drops menu on hover appears on top of the page when display is 600px wide(media rule). I dont understand why

```
buttonDiv:hover menu {
    display:block;
}
```

(#prsut:hover #Izbornik) wont work.
i put html and css in snippets, and now i can see only html code so i hope you can see them both
Sorry, I didn't write code in English
thank you for help

```js
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexp) {
  var re = new RegExp(regexp);
  return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
}, $.validator.format("ne valja regex"));

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#forma").validate({
    rules: {
      dostavaIme: {
        required: true,
        regex: "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
      },
      dostavaAdresa: {
        required: true,
        regex: "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
      },
      dostavaPostanskiBroj: {
        required: true,
        regex: "^[0-9]+$",
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 5
      },
      dostavaTelefon: {
        required: true,
        regex: "[+][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
      }
    },
    messages: {

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="widtd=device-widtd, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-validation-1.16.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-validation-1.16.0/demo/css/screen.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./wrd_files/stilovi.css">
  <title>WRD ispit</title>

</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <div id=prsut style="text-align: left;font-size:30px;margin: 20px;">
      <a id="IzbornikDugme">☰</a><span>BROJ INDEXA</span>
    </div>

    <div id="Izbornik" style="clear:botd">
      <a class="IzbornikStavka" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="IzbornikStavka" href="#">AMF 1</a>
      <a class="IzbornikStavka" href="#">AMF 2</a>
      <a class="IzbornikStavka" href="#">AMF 3</a>
      <a class="IzbornikStavka" href="#">AMF 4</a>
      <a class="IzbornikStavka" href="#">AMF 5</a>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div id="wrapper">

    <div>
      <h1>Iznajmljivanje nekretnine</h1>
      <hr />
    </div>
    <label>Odaberite vilu</label>
    <div class="Kontejner">
      <div class="VilaKolonaWrapper">
        <img class="VilaKolonaOkvir" src="./wrd_files/team2.jpg" />
        <h3>Villa Mostar</h3>
        <h4>100 KM po danu</h4>
        <p class="VilaOpis">Villa u odlicnom stanju. Na klizistu, nije puno presla. Uskoro u centru Mostara</p>
      </div>

      <div class="VilaKolonaWrapper">
        <img class="VilaKolonaOkvir" src="./wrd_files/team1.jpg" />
        <h3>Villa Buna - Blagaj</h3>
        <h4>120 KM po danu</h4>
        <p class="VilaOpis">Odlicna za inznajmljivanje turistima i odlicnim studentima.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="VilaKolonaWrapper">
        <img class="VilaKolonaOkvir" src="./wrd_files/team3.jpg" />
        <h3>Villa Vlašić</h3>
        <h4>130 KM po danu</h4>
        <p class="VilaOpis">Buduće kancelarije FIT-a. Iskreno se nadamo.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Kontejner">
    </div>
    <div id="zaFormu" style="">
      <form id=forma>
        <label for="dostavaIme">Ime</label>
        <input id="dostavaIme" name="dostavaIme" placeholder="kupac ime" />

        <label for="dostavaAdresa">Adresa</label>
        <input id="dostavaAdresa" name="dostavaAdresa" placeholder="kupac adresa" />

        <label for="dostavaPostanskiBroj">Poštanski broj</label>
        <input id="dostavaPostanskiBroj" name="dostavaPostanskiBroj" value="" />

        <label for="dostavaTelefon">Telefon</label>
        <input id="dostavaTelefon" name="dostavaTelefon" placeholder="+387-61-888-8888" />

        <label for="napomena">Napomena</label>
        <textarea id="napomena" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Dodaj kupca" />
      </form>
      <label for="filtiranje">Filtriraj podatke po imenu</label>
      <input id="filtiranje" placeholder="upisi dio imena" />
      <table id="tabelaID" border="1px" style="width: 100%">
        <tdead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id Kupca</th>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Ime</th>
            <th>Adresa</th>
            <th>Poštanski broj</th>
            <th>Telefon</th>
            <th>Napomena</th>
          </tr>
        </tdead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id=cr>
      <p>Copyright by FIT</p>
    </div>

    <script src="./wrd_files/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```